# Spotlight not jumping to app window

Tags: spotlight

New to Mac and if I noticed correctly, an app launched via Spotlight jumps to it/focuses/brings to front even though Spotlight was invoked on another Desktop. It still works in the same Desktop but not between. Is this a problem of Spotlight's index?

Edit: To state more precisely:
I hit cmd+space and launch Notes, for example. It opens on Desktop1.
I create Desktop2, switch to it and try to launch Notes via Spotlight again. This time, it doesn't bring to front Notes which resides on Desktop1.
I was under the assumption that this used to work. Regardless from which Desktop I launch an app via Spotlight it would jump to that Desktop and bring to front the app.

Edit: I believe toggling this and restarting an app fixed the issue:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer (and accept it). It'll avoid the Community bot bumping your question as unsolved

Answer (score 0):

I believe toggling the following and restarting an app fixed the issue

[image]